# .load() not working on ul li click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

here is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#work").click(function(){
    $("#container").load("about/work.html");
  });
  $("#profile").click(function(){
    $("#container").load("profile.html");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a id="work" href="">work</a></li>
  <li><a id="profile" href="">profile</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="container"></div>
```

when i click on work or profile requested page just flashes in container div and sometime stays in but if i run same script on button click it loads page without any problem. How can i make it work with li ?

Comment: did you check for any error on your browser console. ?

Comment: Your click handlers won't stop the browser to execute the default behavior of a link: go to the location defined in the `href` attribute (empty value = this very same location) -> [`.preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Comment: Don't leave your `href` as an empty string. give it a value : `href="#"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `event.preventDefault`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#work").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); //changed here
    $("#container").load("about/work.html");
  });
  $("#profile").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); //changed here
    $("#container").load("profile.html");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things to be changed here.

1) Try not leaving your `href` value empty. If you do then the browser will redirect to the same page. Give it a value `#` if possible `href="#"`

2) There is `preventDefault()` function missing from your `<a>` click event

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#work").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#container").load("about/work.html");
    });
    $("#profile").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#container").load("profile.html");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try to `on` `click`

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#work").on("click", function() {
        $("#container").load("about/work.html");
    });
});
```